# Assigning values to a class dynamically

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have a python class like this

```
class Car(Base):

    def __init__(self, details):
        for field,value in details.iteritems():
            self[field] = value
```

and I call it like this

```
car_details['make'] = 'Dodge'
car_details['model'] = 'Ram'

car = Car(car_details)
```

however it fails with

```
TypeError: 'Car' object does not support item assignment
```

I am trying to set it up, so I can then just use `car.make` once the class has been init.

Comment: The title is misleading. You're trying to use a class instance as dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looking for `setattr()`:

```
def __init__(self, details):
    for field,value in details.iteritems():
        setattr(self, field, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Alex Martelli's Bunch](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/?in=user-97991):

```
class Car(Base):    
    def __init__(self, details):
        self.__dict__.update(details)
```

Note that if you change the `__init__` call signature to `def __init__(self, **details)`:

```
class Car(Base):    
    def __init__(self, **details):
        super(Car,self).__init__(**details)
```

then you can make the initialization of `Car` even easier:

```
car=Car(make='Dodge',model='Ram')
```

Answer (score 0):

See [a dict whose items can also be accessed as member variables](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/361668/).